Adobe Illustrator, can't export shape as a SVG file
I have some basic knowledge of adobe illustrator, I have downloaded one graphics open file from Freepik, Now when I am trying to export the selection in a SVG form and trying to paste it in Figma (Designing Tool)
The SVG vector is behaving as a JPEG image.

This I am trying to export as a SVG, but when I am opening the exported SVG in Figma. It is behaving like a image instead of a vector.
Below is the image when I am trying to open it using Figma (Design Tool)



SVG does not support gradient meshes. So when you export your file as SVG, Illustrator converts your mesh into a png.

is there any way to deal with it?

@SumitYadav you can try importing the ai file to Figma (I do not own Figma to test) or recreate the gradient mesh in Figma. Check out this video How To Create Mesh Gradients in Figma (Beginner Tutorial)

I think I might have confused you, I don't want to create the gradient mesh in Figma. I want the shape I highlighted in red as a vector format so that I can change its color accordingly.

@SumitYadav you will have to change the mesh to a solid fill color. Save as an SVG. You will then be able to change the fill color in Figma.
